# Thread Synchronization - Critical Section or Mutex?

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, synchronization, mutex

If I need to synchronize two threads that both call a function with send() on a specific socket, would it be more useful to warp a critical section on the send() function or look into using a mutex? (since a socket is a kernel object)

Comment: On some OSs the send() call is in itself threadsafe already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that this is about Windows (can't recall seeing critical section elsewhere).

It doesn't matter really which synchronization object you use if all the locking is within one process. If you want to lock across process boundary, then you should use mutex because critical section only works within single process, but named mutex can be shared between many processes.

Comment: actually it matters cos mutex is a kernel object and takes much longer to acquire it, when critical section falls down to kernel mode only for waiting if it's already locked. Otherwise (typically majority of cases) it's pretty fast. Long time ago I saw numbers, something like ~20 CPU instructions to lock a free critical section and ~1000 CPU instructions to acquire a free mutex.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming Windows platform (that's where we have a choice between critical sections and mutexes).

Mutex (of `CreateMutex`) is way slower: locking and unlocking is always a system call, even if there is no contention. The cost of `send`, though, is likely to be enough to make this difference unnoticeable.

As pointed by another answer, mutexes can be shared between processes (if named/reopened or inherited), and critical sections are process-local.

Answer (score -2):

I think, mutex should work faster.

Comment: Critical sections on windows are supposed to be faster than mutexes. Although they have more restrictions. One such restriction is critical sections can only be used inside a process.